# How to store the queried MySQL values from different Columns of the same row in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to get some values from selected columns but from the same row. I managed to get the data from the desired row, but having issues with the data storing and displaying. How can I store the values from the different column (4333, 3444, 2222, 1) into variables for further computations. Thanks.

```
deviceEUI = "00137a10000129a9"


command = ("SELECT `Current_1`, `Current_2`, `Current_3`, `Multiplier_1` from `Current Data` WHERE `Device EUI` =%s ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1")
cursor.execute(command, (deviceEUI,))
results = cursor.fetchall()

print(type(results))

print(results)
```

Output:

<class 'list'>

[(Decimal('4333.00'), Decimal('3444.00'), Decimal('2222.00'), Decimal('1.00'))]

Comment: Hi guys, is it because the queried data is in a tuple, hence storing the values into one list element? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea any way.

Retrieve the data of the specific columns you want,
Create an insert statement.
Write a conditional statement to insert the retrieved data into your new table where you want the retrieved data stored.

Think about this and do your manipulation.

Comment: I found out using the len function that it is storing the entire queried data into ONE element in the list. Is there any solutions for me to store the values into different element?

Comment: You have to create columns to equate the number of columns you want to retrieve